# Is C# going existential on me?

Tags: c#

For some reason an if(false) seems to be actually working. The ReferenceEquals call is in there as an extra test. Before it was just user==null which came out as false and yet the if statement still preceded to..

[UPDATE]
This is a SharePoint/ASP.Net enviroment so yes it's multithreaded. However none of the code I've written is doing any threading. This is a simple enough call results in a boolean type that an if statement seems to think false=true. I've tried a clean solution, restarting the dev enviroment, restarting the machine. I can't find any evidence that the code in the debugger is different to whats being executed.

[NOTE]
The code isn't very good as I've hacked it around a bit to try different things and investigate why this is going a bit wrong. Don't hold the bad code against me. For example userFound should really be named userNotFound

[alt text http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/6869/snippit.png](http://img228.imageshack.us/img228/6869/snippit.png)

Comment: Is this a question? Try posting code instead of an unreadable VS screenshot

Comment: Open the image outside of this page and it is bigger.

Comment: The screenshot is there because I don't quite believe what it's doing myself

Comment: same and if you want it clearer right click and open the image.

Comment: If your question is **"Is C# going existential on me?"** then if an exception was thrown and nobody was around to catch it, did it really happen?

Comment: Wow. If you throw a Console.WriteLine(userObject), does it contradict your debugger's impossible output?

Comment: The question is basically a good one and within SO's remit, but it needs a better title and better explanation than "The picture pretty much explains it".

Comment: You *could* trim the screenshot a little... you know, just kinda highlight the relevant portion where your debugger is in the block of an if statement that evaluates to false.

Comment: And, BTW, some of us "old folks" still have to strain my eyes to see what you meant, even on a 1440x900 screen, with the picture expanded (thanks, Greg).

Comment: I trimmed the image and edited it for you. You're welcome. :)

Comment: Heh I just did it as well. Thanks thou

Comment: well nothing there about the Being of being or the Existence of existance. So i guess its not

Comment: Don't name it "userNotFound". Variables with names that have negations in them are hard to reason about because you run into double negatives. "if (!userNotFound && ... )" is hard to read. Either keep it as "userFound" and get the logic right, or rename it "userMissing".

Answer (score 18):

Try doing a clean build?  It's possible the code in the IDE doesn't exactly match the code being debugged.

Comment: That has happened to me before with SharePoint but I can't find any evidence that it's doing it this time.

Comment: I'm thinking there may be an older version of code in one of the ASP.NET cache locations?

Comment: One way to detect a dirty build would be to press Ctrl+Alt+D to switch to the Disassembly view (and Ctrl+D, R to show the registers) so you can see what's really happening.  Then again, you could just do a Clean and Build.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why you're getting that strange result. But the code does look *wrong*.  "userFound" is *true* if "userObject" is *null* ? Surely the user is *found* if the user object is *not null*.

The rest of the visible code assumes that "userFound == true" actually means "user was not found" as well.

This code would be a lot less confusing if you renamed the variable "userIsMissing".

Comment: what you point out is an artifact of me hacking this around to try different things. That originally read !userFound

Comment: That strongly suggests you've got the old binary in memory!

Comment: John is exactly right. That is almost certainly what is going on here. You are using source code that does not match the binary image you are debugging. There should be a way to set up VS so that it warns you when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

are you doing some type of threading. also i dont recall correctly but could it be that the code you are debugging it's outdated compare to the one you are seeing in the code editor?

try negating user found and see if the behavior is the opposite if it is there's something in the code if not there's something with visual studio ie. c# going existential on you

Answer (score 0):

It's a SharePoint site. It's running ASP.NET. It's multi-threaded. Are you sure yours is the only request?

Is it a Release build, or a Debug build? Need I elaborate?

Comment: the SS shows debug under project configuration i dont know a lot about sharepoint and asp.net but is that what you mean by debug?

Comment: No, I meant is the code build in debug mode. The configuration you're referring to is no guarantee that the code we see was built in Debug mode.

Comment: ahh gotcha i understand what you mean now. he could have build in debug and then accidentally switched to release.

Comment: It's a singer user development machine. Only my request is running on it. It's running in debug mode

Answer (score 0):

Delete the dll's and pdb's from your bin/debug folders, recompile and try again.

Comment: I've tried this. I also deleted the assembly from the GAC and did an iisreset to ensure there won't be any old copies of it kicking around

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, have you tried printing out the value of the boolean?  Printing to the console or writing to the page, whatever.

Sometimes magical voodoo happens, but printing out values always helps for me.

Debuggers are convenient but I don't always trust them.

Comment: You've got a point, but I know that the bool is false like the debugger says. The ReferenceEquals call will be false because userObject won't be null.